# How to configure fail2ban so it bans login attempts based on the structure of the attempted password or username

Tags: security, fail2ban

I want to set up two filters for fail2ban:

1. If the user tries to login with a password that is less than 10 characters ban them. And if the user tries to login with a password that is more than 10 characters but the last letter isn't eg z, ban them.
2. If the users tries to login as root, ban them. I would also like to give this rule a custom ban time that is extra long - eg 1 day, compared to my other ban rules which has a milder punishment.

How would I set these up. Number 1 is particularly interesting to me. Number 2 is to catch people out as I will never be logging in as root and have disabled root logins.

Thank you

Comment: I can't imagine you're going to find any program that writes password length or content information to the syslog-- that would be a major security risk. Certainly, OpenSSH won't. That takes your item 1 off the table.

Comment: Why is that a security risk? So long as it's only incorrect logins being logged and it's their length and final character not the whole password...

Comment: When a legitimate user mis-enters their password such a "feature" would leak information about the character of their password. I would agree that it's a small leak, but its still a leak. The Right Answer(tm) is to use public key authentication and stop using passwords.

Comment: But how will the attackers access the log file to see the leak? If they can see the log file that means they already have the password, so it wouldn't matter at that point? Or are log files publicly accessible? Thanks

Comment: I think you're talking about a single-user machine and in that case, you're right, once they have your password they have your password. I'm thinking more broadly-- a multi-user machine where an attacker, after they're rooted the host, is going to comb through configurations, logs, etc, to find information that can be used to attack other hosts. If I were pentesting an environment with the hypothetical bad password reporting you describe I'd certainly love to get that information because it would make my job brute-forcing or cracking passwords easier. In general, no, your logs aren't public.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the information! Yes it's a single-user machine. Just trying to lock it down as hard as I can

Comment: If its a single user machine, then why have the "openness" of a password, like how you specified in your question? If you are going to use passwords (see Evan Anderson's comment), then why not just ban anyone that fails to enter the correct password? Perhaps set a buffer of 2 or 3 attempts, just in case you have some butterfingers that day.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this and IMHO it's not a great idea, but if you insist you'll need to write a pam module that does the appropriate logging to syslog for fail2ban to read and implement.

Ssh and pam is a whole 'nuther kettle of fish, but for this usage it should be reasonably straightforward.

After you've written your custom pam module, you should put it in the pam stack after the module you are using does sufficient auth so it will only be applied to
failed logins.

http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_MWG.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there an easier way to do it if I only want to look at the username trying to log in? Or is it equally as involved.

Comment: The standard ssh filters should work for just looking at usernames. OpenSSH makes logging that very straightforward.

Comment: Could you give an example to use in your answer? I am not a proficient linux user.

Comment: Basically if someone tries to login with the 'root' username I want them banned for a week